# Reliably identify sender in Exchange SmtpReceiveAgent

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2013

I use Exchange as a simple SMTP server and I want to take specific actions depending on who the sender is.

I made a connector which allow basic authentication (auth login) and a SmtpReceicveAgent.

I tried to retrieve the logged user in the code of my connector with no luck, the only thing I can get is the mail properties like FROM which is not reliable. I looked at all events available but it seems that any of them gives me the user's login.

For reference, here is mdsn's page about [these events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.smtp.smtpreceiveagent_events%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).
Most of them gives the [SmtpSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.smtp.smtpsession_members%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) object in the args but it doesn't help.

I also gave a try to OnEndOfAuthentication event which has a property "RemoteIdentityName". However it returns "CAS01" which is the name of a Client Access Server.

any clue on how to determine the login of the user currently sending the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the SmtpReceiveAgent from the mailbox server and installed it on the Client Access Server instead and now the given "RemoteIdentityName" is correct